# WPF scrolling menu

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I would like to make a WPF menu structure like Windows Media Center's Music Library interface.  Basically, the premise is there is a list of categories and items.  You can use the left / right arrow keys to scroll the categories. The available categories "wrap" around the screen, with the second item in the list always being the selected one. The available items for that category are in a list below the categories.  While you are in the categories, you can press the down arrow to navigate to the list, doing so causes the categories above to 'drop' a font size and fade out a tad, and the list items to pop up a font size and fade in a tad.  While in the list of items, you can now navigate the items left, right, up, down.  If you press up on the top most row of items you will be back in the categories list and cause it to pop up a font size and the items pop down a font size.

I am a total WPF noob... any guidance would be appreciated.

Best example is to try the WMC music library interface -- however for those of you who do not have it installed, I have included a couple screen shots:

[image: WMC Category Navigation]
[image: WMC Item Navigation]

Comment: So what have you tried until now to achieve this? Saying your new to WPF isn't very helpful cos your not comfortable with basic UI design with WPF yet you've jumped straight into replicating a fully fledged app that might involve quite a bit of things. My typical answer for this would be along the lines of "Yeh totally doable, Have an `ItemsControl` with a `WrapPanel` as its `PanelTemplate` and `ItemTemplate` to have accompanying `Storyboard` for their required animations within a `Canvas` background".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something:

[image]

For the base I took element **TabControl**, by the your screenshot he is most suitable. Besides, it may be an TabItem any control (like **DataGrid**). First you need to add the navigation arrows in TabItem (it represents a category) and the need for them to hide unselected TabItem. To do it correctly, you need to do it in the template of TabItem (App.xaml):

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type TabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="./#Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />            
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Name="Border" Margin="0,0,2,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0">
                        <Grid>
                            <!-- There are arrow Prev and Next -->
                            <Button Name="PrevButton" Style="{StaticResource PrevButton}" />
                            <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" ContentSource="Header" />
                            <Button Name="NextButton" Style="{StaticResource NextButton}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- Here is hiding the arrows -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="PrevButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            <Setter TargetName="NextButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F4F4F4" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Style for arrows button (App.xaml):

```
    <!-- Prev button style -->
    <Style x:Key="PrevButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Prev" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            <Path x:Name="PrevButton" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="13" Height="16" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Gray" Data="F1 M 35.8724,37.6042L 39.0391,40.7708L 50.5182,51.8542L 40.2266,51.8542L 25.1849,37.6041L 40.2266,23.3542L 50.5182,23.3542L 39.0391,34.4375L 35.8724,37.6042 Z " />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="PrevButton" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="PrevButton" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Next button style -->
    <Style x:Key="NextButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,3,0" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Next" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            <Path x:Name="NextButton" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="13" Height="16" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Gray" Data="F1 M 39.8307,37.6042L 36.6641,34.4375L 25.1849,23.3542L 35.4766,23.3542L 50.5182,37.6042L 35.4766,51.8542L 25.1849,51.8542L 36.6641,40.7708L 39.8307,37.6042 Z " />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="NextButton" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="NextButton" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Main window XAML:

```
    <TabControl Name="SampleTabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Loaded="TabControl_Loaded">
        <TabItem Name="Soccer" Header="Soccer">
            <ListBox Name="SoccerListBox" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Ronaldo</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Messi</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Sergio Ramos</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Puyol</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Name="Hockey" Header="Hockey">
            <ListBox Name="HockeyListBox" BorderThickness="0">
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Cal Heeter</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Jeff Petry</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Erik Johnson</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Matt Hunwick</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Name="Basketbol" Header="Basketbol">
            <ListBox Name="BasketbolListBox" BorderThickness="0">
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Kobe Bryant</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Chris Paul</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Carmelo Anthony</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: LeBron James</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Name="Baseball" Header="Baseball">
            <ListBox Name="BaseballListBox" BorderThickness="0">
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Ralph Kiner</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Dizzy Dean</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Duke Snider</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Player name: Ozzie Smith</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Now you need to make a functional arrows workers. To do this, create a **TabControl_Loaded** event, where we find the buttons from a template, and assign them to the event handlers:

```
    private void TabControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var items = SampleTabControl.Items;

        foreach (TabItem item in items)
        {
            Button MyPrevButton = (Button)item.Template.FindName("PrevButton", item);
            Button MyNextButton = (Button)item.Template.FindName("NextButton", item);

            MyPrevButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MyPrevButton_Click);
            MyNextButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MyNextButton_Click);
        }
    }
```

Event handlers:

```
    private void MyPrevButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationTabItem(SampleTabControl, "Prev", 1);
    }

    private void MyNextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationTabItem(SampleTabControl, "Next", 1);
    }
```

For ease of navigation function was created:

```
    private void NavigationTabItem(TabControl MyTabControl, string Direction, int Num) 
    {
        if (Direction == "Prev")
        {
            MyTabControl.SelectedIndex -= Num;
        }

        if (Direction == "Next")
        {
            MyTabControl.SelectedIndex += Num;
        }
    }
```

Now we need to intercept the keyboard interface. To do this, the handler was created and installed on the window (it is better to install it on TabControl, and when program start to put it focus):

```
<Window ... KeyDown="SampleTabControl_KeyDown">

    private void SampleTabControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down) 
        {
            if (SampleTabControl.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                SoccerListBox.Focus();
            }

            if (SampleTabControl.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                HockeyListBox.Focus();
            }

            if (SampleTabControl.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                BasketbolListBox.Focus();
            }

            if (SampleTabControl.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                BaseballListBox.Focus();
            }
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        {
            NavigationTabItem(SampleTabControl, "Prev", 1);
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            NavigationTabItem(SampleTabControl, "Next", 1);
        }
    }
```

As optional be set to select an animation on ListBoxItem and TabItem.